# Deploy ASP.NET Web Application Identity Database

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I deploy the ASP Identity database (contains AspNetRoles, AspNetUserClaims, AspNetUserLogins, AspNetUserRoles, AspNetUsers tables) in a Web Deploy Package?  I'm using WebForms not MVC.  I'm having problems finding a walkthrough.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know how to do that via Web Deploy, but if you want to do manually follow one of this options :

you have multiple options :

1. install SQL Server Express LocalDB on your Hosting Server,
2. Connect to (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB via SQL Server Management Studio and Generate Scripts for your localDB Database (this database usually named like this : aspnet-something-20180906103305) and then execute that SQL Script on your Web Server Database.